# Two animations one after another

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to make 2 animation on activity for 2 images, and I want to do it with 2 conditions: 
1. I want to start the animation after the activity finished to load to page, so instead of putting animation code under `onCreate` i put it under `onResume` is that OK? There is a better way to do it? 
2. I want the second animation will start only after the first animation is finished...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an [Animation.AnimationListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) You can set one on your first animation that will get a callback when the animation is complete. Inside that callback you can add the code that will start the second animation.

Comment: OK I'll try that, But regarding to my first question, is that OK to put animation code under onResume?

Comment: Sure as long as you are sure you want it to happen every time onResume gets called. And (I mentiontion this as a user not a programmer) don't make the animation total duration very long. If the duration is too long that I feel like I have to wait to use it then it begins to annoy me.

Comment: Can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899280/multiple-xml-animation-is-not-working @FoamyGuy

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the API level you are coding for you can use `AnimationSet` or `AnimatorSet`.  Also if you are extending `View` or one of its subclasses you can override `View.onAnimationStart()` and `View.onAnimationFinish()`. Or use the listener Tim mentions.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

        Animation FadeInanimation, FadeOutanimation;
        ImageView img;

        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
                //Your Code Block....

                FadeInanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.image_fadein);
                //FadeInanimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                //FadeInanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
                FadeInanimation.setAnimationListener(FadeInAnimationListener);

                FadeOutanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.image_fadeout);
                //FadeOutanimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                //FadeOutanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
                FadeOutanimation.setAnimationListener(fadeOutAnimationListener);

                img.startAnimation(FadeInanimation);
            }
    AnimationListener FadeInAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                plane.startAnimation(FadeOutanimation);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: you can put animation onResume() it's work. every time ur application start with onResume then ur animation starts. if u put your animation in onCreate method then its called first time when your application starts when u switch ur application at that time ur app. in pause mode and then u back to your app. call onResume methode at that time your animation not start beacoze of animation write on onCreate method